# Application Laravel 8 + Livewire dynamically check value into a script

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am developing an application with laravel 8 and livewire.

In my app I need to show in a table the data taken from the DB and grouped by month and year, and this I can do and it works correctly.

Then from this dataset, I take the values of the three most recent years, for example `2021, 2020, 2019` and use them to populate a chart.

When I do the first render I get the correct behavior and the graph is shown.
But when I go to filter the data in the table by `imposta` it is possible that for the specific `imposta` type there are less than three years of data and therefore I get an error `Undefined offset: year` for the year not present.

How can I find out if the year exists or not? i've tried with a if-else statement into the script but don't work.

Any advice or suggestion is appreciated

My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Report pagamenti per anno</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row page-titles mx-0">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 p-md-0">
                        <div class="welcome-text">
                            <h4>Filtra</h4>
                            <div wire:ignore class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                                <label>Anno di riferimento</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="annoRif" wire:model="filter.anno"
                                    name="anno" style="width:220px;">
                                    <option value="false">Tutti</option>
                                    @if (!empty($anni))
                                        @foreach ($anni as $an)
                                            <option wire:key="{{ $loop->index }}" value="{{ $an->year }}">
                                                {{ $an->year }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div wire:ignore class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                                <label>Imposta</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="imposta" wire:model="filter.imposta"
                                    name="imposta" style="width:220px;">
                                    <option value="false">Tutte</option>
                                    @if (!empty($nomi_imposta))
                                        @foreach ($nomi_imposta as $n)
                                            <option wire:key="{{ $loop->index }}" value="{{ $n->id }}">
                                                @if ($n->descrizione_sintetica != '')
                                                    {{ $n->descrizione_sintetica }}
                                                @else
                                                    {{ $n->descrizione_imposta }}
                                                @endif
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-responsive-md" style="min-width: 845px">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Anno pagamento</th>
                                <th>Gennaio</th>
                                <th>Febbraio</th>
                                <th>Marzo</th>
                                <th>Aprile</th>
                                <th>Maggio</th>
                                <th>Giugno</th>
                                <th>Luglio</th>
                                <th>Agosto</th>
                                <th>Settembre</th>
                                <th>Ottobre</th>
                                <th>Novembre</th>
                                <th>Dicembre</th>
                                <th>TOTALE</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @if (!empty($report))
                                <?php $tot = 0.0; ?>
                                @foreach ($report as $key => $value)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $key }}</td>
                                        @if (isset($value[1]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[1] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[1]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[2]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[2] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[2]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[3]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[3] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[3]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[4]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[4] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[4]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[5]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[5] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[5]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[6]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[6] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[6]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[7]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[7] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[7]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[8]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[8] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[8]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[9]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[9] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[9]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[10]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[10] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[10]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[11]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[11] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[11]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if (isset($value[12]))
                                            <td>{{ $value[12] }} &euro;</td>
                                            <?php $tot += $value[12]; ?>
                                        @else
                                            <td>0 &euro;</td>
                                        @endif
                                        <td>{{ $tot }} &euro;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php $tot = 0.0; ?>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <th>Anno pagamento</th>
                            <th>Gennaio</th>
                            <th>Febbraio</th>
                            <th>Marzo</th>
                            <th>Aprile</th>
                            <th>Maggio</th>
                            <th>Giugno</th>
                            <th>Luglio</th>
                            <th>Agosto</th>
                            <th>Settembre</th>
                            <th>Ottobre</th>
                            <th>Novembre</th>
                            <th>Dicembre</th>
                            <th>TOTALE</th>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- grafico report pagamenti per anno -->
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Report dei pagamenti incassati negli ultimi tre anni</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="morris_bar" class="morris_chart_height"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; align: center">
                <p style="margin-left:15px;">Anni di pagamento:<br />
                   @if(!empty($anni[0]['year'])) <span class="badge badge-sm badge-primary"><label>{{ $anni[0]['year'] }}</label></span> @endif
                   @if(!empty($anni[1]['year'])) <span class="badge badge-sm badge-success"><label>{{ $anni[1]['year'] }}</label></span> @endif
                   @if(!empty($anni[2]['year'])) <span class="badge badge-sm badge-warning" style="color:white;"><label>{{ $anni[2]['year'] }}</label></span> @endif
                </p>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@push('custom_scripts')
    <script>
        //Codice per popolare il grafico
        var screenWidth = $(window).width();

        var setChartWidth = function() {
            if (screenWidth <= 768) {
                var chartBlockWidth = 0;
                chartBlockWidth = (screenWidth < 300) ? screenWidth : 300;
                jQuery('.morris_chart_height').css('min-width', chartBlockWidth - 31);
            }
        }
        // VALORI HARD CODED SOLO A FINI DI TEST DI STAMPA A VIDEO DEL GRAFICO
        // VANNO POI MODIFICATI PER ESSERE DINAMICI
        
        // HERE I'VE THE ERROR AFTER FILTERING DATA
        if(typeof {!! $anni[0]["year"] !!} !== 'undefined'){
            let anno0 = {!! json_encode($report[$anni[0]['year']]) !!};
        }else{ let anno0 = null; }
    
        if(typeof {!! $anni[1]["year"] !!} !== 'undefined'){
            let anno1 = {!! json_encode($report[$anni[1]['year']]) !!};
        }else{ let anno1 = null; }
    
        if(typeof {!! $anni[2]["year"] !!} !== 'undefined'){
            let anno2 = {!! json_encode($report[$anni[2]['year']]) !!};
        }else{ let anno2 = null; }
        
        //totale dinamico
        var total0 = 0.00;
        var total1 = 0.00;
        var total2 = 0.00;

        if (null !== anno0 || null !== anno1 || null !== anno2) {
            Object.keys(anno0).forEach(function(k) {
                total0 = total0 + anno0[k];
            });

            Object.keys(anno1).forEach(function(k) {
                total1 = total1 + anno1[k];
            });

            Object.keys(anno2).forEach(function(k) {
                total2 = total2 + anno2[k];
            });

            let Data = [{
                y: 'Gennaio',
                a: anno0["1"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["1"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["1"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["1"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["1"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["1"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Febbraio',
                a: anno0["2"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["2"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["2"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["2"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["2"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["2"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Marzo',
                a: anno0["3"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["3"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["3"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["3"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["3"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["3"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Aprile',
                a: anno0["4"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["4"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["4"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["4"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["4"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["4"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Maggio',
                a: anno0["5"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["5"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["5"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["5"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["5"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["5"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Giugno',
                a: anno0["6"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["6"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["6"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["6"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["6"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["6"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Luglio',
                a: anno0["7"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["7"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["7"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["7"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["7"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["7"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Agosto',
                a: anno0["8"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["8"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["8"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["8"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["8"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["8"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Settembre',
                a: anno0["9"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["9"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["9"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["9"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["9"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["9"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Ottobre',
                a: anno0["10"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["10"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["10"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["10"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["10"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["10"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Novembre',
                a: anno0["11"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["11"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["11"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["11"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["11"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["11"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'Dicembre',
                a: anno0["12"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno0["12"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                b: anno1["12"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno1["12"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
                c: anno2["12"] !== undefined ? parseFloat(anno2["12"], 10).toFixed(2) : 0,
            }, {
                y: 'TOTALE',
                a: total0.toFixed(2),
                b: total1.toFixed(2),
                c: total2.toFixed(2),
            }];
            var barChart = Morris.Bar({
                element: 'morris_bar',
                data: Data,
                xkey: 'y',
                ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                labels: ['{{ $anni[0]["year"] }}', '{{ $anni[1]["year"] }}', '{{ $anni[2]["year"] }}'],
                barColors: ['#3a7afe', '#10ca93', '#ff9f00'],
                hideHover: 'auto',
                gridLineColor: 'rgba(80, 63, 88, 0.56)',
                resize: true,
                barSizeRatio: 0.45,
            });
        }

    </script>
@endpush
```